How to access serialized data (message payload) in Go gRPC without re-marshaling in an interceptor?
Im working with gRPC in Go and want to access the raw serialized data (in its wire format) directly in a gRPC interceptor without needing to re-marshal the data. In older versions of gRPC, I was able to capture this serialized data using a stats.Handler by implementing the HandleRPC method and accessing the .Data field from the *stats.InPayload case.
func (h *myStatsHandler) HandleRPC(ctx context.Context, s stats.RPCStats) {
    switch payload := s.(type) {
    case *stats.InPayload:
        // Access serialized data here
        rawData := payload.Data
    }
}

Now, I'm looking for a way to capture this serialized request data in an interceptor or any other mechanism that avoids the overhead of re-marshaling the request. The goal is to avoid doing something like:
data, err := proto.Marshal(req) // I want to bypass this extra marshalling step

Is there a way to access the raw serialized request data in the newer versions of gRPC in Go, or any alternative approach to efficiently retrieve it in the interceptor context?
Previously, I used the stats.Handler to capture serialized request data directly from the *stats.InPayload case. By accessing the .Data field, I could retrieve the raw request data without needing to marshal it again. This worked well in older versions of gRPC.
However, in newer versions, the .Data field has been removed, and I can no longer capture the serialized request data this way. I was expecting to find a similar field or method in the newer gRPC API that would allow me to access this data directly in the interceptor, but I haven't found a clear solution.
I need to avoid manually marshalling the request again, as it introduces unnecessary overhead. I'm looking for a more efficient way to access the raw serialized request data.

What versions of gRPC Go are you using?

Latest : v1.67.1 .
That option is available in v1.66.0-dev.0.20240729170412-ec9dff77b186.

Depending on what you're trying to do, making a custom encoding.Codec that wraps the default one would give you access to the encoded bytes.

I need to implement functionality similar to what was previously available in the stats handler, which allowed for materialized data to be passed to the interceptor before reaching the handler.  discussion : https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/issues/7794
